# C++ stringstreams skipping a character

Tags: c++, stringstream

I have a file which the first line reads ">FileName.txt". My goal is to read this line, and save "FileName.txt" to a variable called name. So I have:

```
ifstream file;

/* File opening stuff */

string line, name;

getline(file,line);

stringstream converter(line);

converter >> name;
```

This accomplishes saving ">FileName.txt" to the variable `name`, but I need to remove the '>' character. I am not sure if I should do that after this point, or if there is a way to skip over it entirely using the `stringstream`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can skip over it with the stream fairly easily:

```
char ch;
converter >> ch; // skip initial >
converter >> name; // now read the name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can skip over it with the function `ignore`, add follow statement after `stringstream converter(line);` only need one line.

```
converter.ignore(line.length(), '>');
```