# How to read from stdin int using c++ skipping "," and "Space" till "\n"

Tags: c++

I want to read integers from STDIN, 
1,2,3,4

```
vector<int> r;
cin >> is;
stringstream iss(is);
int n;
while(iss >> n)
{
    r.push_back(n);
}
```

but stops reading after "," is there a way other than splitting and directly read Integers only.

Comment: `int n; char c; while( iss >> n >> c ) { ... }` Either way, yes, you can split the line by separator.

Comment: @user2296177 `int n; char c; while( iss >> n >> c ) { ... }` will not read the last `int`.

Comment: Also have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21837521/1025391

Answer (score 1):

Here you have to consume and skip the `,` after every digit as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942445/c-stringstreams-skipping-a-character):

```
vector<int> r;
cin >> is;
stringstream iss(is);
int n;
while(iss >> n)
{
    r.push_back(n);
    char c;
    iss >> c;
}
```

See running example [here](http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/Ntantr).